# Using a USB 2.0 WiFi adapter on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I Bought a USB 2.0 WiFi adapter "RTL8188FTV" and when I tried it in windows it took 30 seconds and it worked , but when i tried it with ubuntu (20.04.1) it didn't work , so before i tried an older USB adapter and it worked with Ubuntu no problem , so probablly this means it is drivers problem , so I found this : https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

so the first 2 steps needs an internet connection to be done , but I don't have internet on Ubuntu.

so is there any way I can do those 2 first steps with windows , i mean like download the files manually and put them in a USB and reboot to Ubuntu.

Comment: You did notice the driver ends in U and the device name ends in V it is my understanding they are different.

Comment: I didn't find drivers exactly made for "rtl8188ftv" but when i search for it i found that

Comment: I have just heard they are not the same.

Comment: Most USB WiFi adapters are automatically recognized by the Linux kernel, but there are some shady folks in that market. Compiling your own drivers was considered "Linux-compatible"...15 years ago, but certainly not today. Advice: If possible, return the worthless adapter, or exchange it for one that is compatible with Linux. If the manufacturer or vendor claimed the hardware is Linux-compatible, you have conclusively demonstrated that's not true, and that they lied to you. Do not trust liars with your hard-earned money again.

Comment: @user535733 What? Not a good comment. Kind of a rant. What is DKMS used for then?

Comment: You have the right driver. Do you have access to a wired ethernet connection... a router or modem? Purchase this $13 **USB to ethernet** adapter https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00YUU3KC6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and temporarily connect that way, then you can download/install the driver.

Comment: @heynnema perhaps; I am annoyed by false claims in the marketplace. Now the OP has two reasonable ways forward to choose from.

Comment: @heynnema id don't have an ehtnert connection for the moment , but i have acces to a windows pc , ive downloaded drivers to a usb and then reboot to ubuntu , but when i tried to run the commands it told me "dkms command not found"

Comment: That's because you don't have dkms installed. Don't you have direct access to your router or modem or ethernet wall plate? The $13 adapter I quoted would work to get all of the software dependencies installed, without the pain of trying to download them all and put them on a USB flash. You **could** go to packages.ubuntu.com and download dependencies.

Comment: that's an ether to usb , how is it going to work ?
btw can i manually download dkms ?

Comment: But doesn't your Windows have access to the Internet via the router? Or doesn't your router have ethernet LAN ports?

Comment: Yes, you can download dkms at the site that I specified.

Comment: @heynnema thanks , imma try it